# I got 0x1E error (INTEGRITY_ERROR) while change DESFire master key.What are my mistakes?And How can I resolve?

Tags: java, apdu, crc16, contactless-smartcard

### Whole update1: see question again.

I recently am working with `DESFire` cards .I now decide to change defult *master key* of *PICC*.

(I already could authenticate with master key all 8 byte 0x00 successfully)

1- Defult `master key` is 8 `byte` of zero.It is `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.

2-New `master key` that I choosed is 16 `byte`.

It is:

```
byte[] newPICCKey= new byte[]{(byte)0x11, (byte)0x22, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x44,       
                                 (byte)0x55, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x77 ,(byte)0x88, 
                                 (byte)0x12, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x34 ,(byte)0x45 ,
                                 (byte)0x56, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x78 ,(byte)0x89};
```

3- I authenticate with old master key( Still it is not changed and still it is 8 byte of zero.) successfully. 
Random numbers is :

Random A = a 8 byte number

Random B = a 8 byte number

4 - I create the Session key each time by using Random A and Random B :
Session key = first 4 byte of Random A + first 4 byte of Random B

```
//fill sessionKey with RandomA and RandomB
                for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                    sessionKey[i] = randomA[i];
                for(int i=4; i<8; i++)

                    sessionKey[i] = randomB[i-4];
```

5 - i create CRC16 for new master key with bellow method . The result is : D8 EC
(The new PICC master key could be 16 byte? or it must be 8 byte? By the way I choosed a 16 byte value for new master key)

```
 public class CRC16 
{
public static short Crc16(byte[] buffer, short offset, short len) 
    {
short crcTmp = 0x6363;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
        {
            short temp = (short)(buffer[offset + i] ^ crcTmp); 
            temp = (short)((temp ^ (temp << 4)) & 0xff); 
            crcTmp = (short)(((crcTmp >> 8) & 0xff) ^ (temp << 8) ^ (temp << 3) ^ (temp >> 4));
        }
        return crcTmp;
    }

}
```

6 - I create ew PICC key with crc and with padding(deciphered)

```
byte[] newPICCKey_deciphered = new byte[]{(byte)0x11, (byte)0x22, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x44, 
                        (byte)0x55, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x77 ,(byte)0x88, 
                        (byte)0x12, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x34 ,(byte)0x45 ,
                        (byte)0x56, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x78 ,(byte)0x89,
                        (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 };
                txtNewPICCKeyDeciphered.setText(Utils.bytesToHex(newPICCKey_deciphered));
```

7- I calculate crc16 and add it to my new key:

```
short res = CRC16_3.Crc16(newPICCKey, (short)0, (short)16); 
                newPICCKey_deciphered[16] = (byte) (res & 0xFF); 
                newPICCKey_deciphered[17] = (byte) ((res >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

8 - I enciphered above new master key by bellow method and I got a 24 byte enciphered :

```
 byte[] iv1=new byte[]{(byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 ,
                        (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 };
                byte[] newPICCKeyEnciphered = new byte[24];
                //..............................
                byte[] block1 = new byte[]{(byte)0x11, (byte)0x22, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x44, 
                        (byte)0x55, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x77 ,(byte)0x88};
                byte[] block2 = new byte[]{
                (byte)0x11, (byte)0x22, (byte)0x33 ,(byte)0x44 ,
                (byte)0x55, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x77 ,(byte)0x88};
                byte[] block3 = new byte[]{(byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00};
                block3[0] = newPICCKey_deciphered[16];
                block3[1] = newPICCKey_deciphered[17];

   try
                {
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
                SecretKeyFactory desKeyFact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
                DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(sessionKey);  
                SecretKey s = desKeyFact.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, s);

                byte[] r1 = new byte[8];
                r1 =Utils.doXorTwoByteArray(block1, iv1);

                byte[] r2 = new byte[8];
                r2 = cipher.doFinal(r1, 0, 8);
                //...............
                byte[] r3 = new byte[8];
                r3 =Utils.doXorTwoByteArray(block2, r2);

                byte[] r4 = new byte[8];
                r4 =cipher.doFinal(r3, 0, 8);
                //................
                byte[] r5 = new byte[8];
                r5 =Utils.doXorTwoByteArray(block3, r4);

                byte[] r6 = new byte[8];
                r6 =cipher.doFinal(r5, 0, 8);
                for(int i=0; i<8;i++)
                    newPICCKeyEnciphered[i] = r2[i];
                for(int i=8; i<16;i++)
                    newPICCKeyEnciphered[i] = r4[i-8];
                for(int i=16; i<24;i++)
                    newPICCKeyEnciphered[i] = r6[i-16];
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Here is Class DES used at enciphering :

```
public class DES {
    public static byte[] doDecryptData(byte[] OriginalData,byte[]key , int sizeKey , byte[] iv , int sizeIV)
    {
    byte[] masterKeyBytes =new byte[sizeKey];
    masterKeyBytes = key;
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[sizeIV];
     ivBytes = iv;
        byte[] encipheredData=new byte[sizeIV];

        try{

            DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(masterKeyBytes);  
            SecretKeyFactory desKeyFact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey s = desKeyFact.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
            Cipher aliceCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
            aliceCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, s, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

            encipheredData= aliceCipher.doFinal(OriginalData);
            return encipheredData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("error", "111"+e.toString());
            }
        return null;
    }
```

9- And finally I fill parameter byte array and send it with instruction(c4) to the

```
byte[] cmd = new byte[]{(byte)0x00 ,
                         (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 
                         ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 
                         ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 
                         ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 
                         ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 
                         ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 };
                //fill cmd
                for(int i=1 ;i<cmd.length ; i++)
                    cmd[i] = newPICCKeyEnciphered[i -1];

try {
responseChangeKey = isodep.transceive(Utils.wrapMessage((byte)0xC4, cmd));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And here is Utils class:

```
public class Utils {    
    public static byte[] wrapMessage (byte command, byte[] parameters) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        stream.write((byte) 0x90);
        stream.write(command);
        stream.write((byte) 0x00);
        stream.write((byte) 0x00);
        if (parameters != null) {
            stream.write((byte) parameters.length);
            stream.write(parameters);
        }
        stream.write((byte) 0x00);

        byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
        return b;
    }
}
```

I at the last step (sending apdu for changing master key to the card) recieved Exception 0x1E Error, that means Integrity error :CRC or MAC does not match data
Padding bytes not valid.
How can I do perform changing key correctly ? it is necessaryfor me.thanks.

Comment: `block1` and `block2` are the same, that could be the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. DESFire cards uses a little different CRC16 from yours. Your initial value for CRC16 is `0xFFFF`, but DESFire expects `0x6363`. This may cause your troubles with the integrity error.
2. I see no DEC/CBC encryption using decryption of your `newPICCKey_deciphered` array. You really have to use DECRYPTION MODE instead of ENCRYPTION MODE when encrypting (although it seems weird). That means:

`aliceCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, s, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));`

and because of the fact, that CBC mode of decryption is different from CBC mode for encryption, you have to implement your own CBC mode and use the `aliceCipher` always for one block only with the correct IV.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77896/discussion-on-answer-by-vojta-i-got-0x1e-error-integrity-error-while-change-de).

Comment: @setareab Please don't use comments to refer the answerer to your new question. Or simply delete them after receiving your answer. stackoverflow is not supposed to have a lot of reference to other questions of questioner below the answers. so please remove all three above comments. they don't help to future viewer.Thank you. :)  (I'll delete my comment also.)